# How can i combinate push and update from an value in an array?

Tags: javascript

How can i combinate push and update event for an array?

i tried with assign but that was not working

```
$(`#saveall${roomname}`).on('click',function() {
    var tisch = document.getElementById(`${roomname}_tisch`).value;
    item = {};
    item ["tisch"] = tisch;
    itemsnew.push(item);
});
```

the Problem what i have if i update the value i got a new entry :

```
    items: Array(2)
0: {tisch: "3"}
1: {tisch: "6"}
```

i will still update the value from tisch and not new entry in my array

Comment: What is `itemsnew`

Comment: another array for other datas

Comment: update array event?

Answer (score 1):

`{tisch: tisch}` creates the same object in one expression; in fact, in ES6 you can simply use the shorthand `{tisch}`. Given this:

```
itemsnew.push({tisch});
```

Comment: ok but i have more datas not only tisch

Comment: @Dustin Sooo… give us an example of what you *really* want then…?! And you can include more values directly: `{foo: bar, baz: 42}`.

Comment: @deceze actually after i update i got more entrys like this ` items: Array(5)
0: {tisch: "4"}
1: {tisch: "4"}
2: {tisch: "5"}
3: {tisch: "5"}
4: {tisch: "5"}` i want that unique

Comment: @Dustin Use an object instead of an array then…? `itemsnew[tisch] = tisch`…? I really don't know what your goal is.

Comment: @deceze i only want noch more entrys from tisch just 1 and if i update this change value not more

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```js
$(`#saveall${roomname}`).on('click',function() {
  var tisch = document.getElementById(`${roomname}_tisch`).value;
  itemsnew.push({
    tisch, // => this is equivalent to "tisch": tisch
    /* add more properties if you need to */
  });
});
```

Comment: its not only the var tisch i have some more datas there

Comment: Thats not working he still add more entys items: Array(5)
0: {tisch: "4"}
1: {tisch: "4"}
2: {tisch: "5"}
3: {tisch: "5"}
4: {tisch: "5"}